# The share icons are not showing in the home page after a post while i had made the "the_excerpt" in wordpress on

Tags: php, html, wordpress

The site i am working is http://www.nickthepromisering.com/

If you go there you can find that the "the_excerpt" is on.

The main problem is that the "share this" icons are not visble after every posts. but they are visible when we enter into the post

Forexample: In the home page after the post "UFC coming to Calgary??" the share this icon are not visble but they are visible when we enter into that post

That is http://www.nickthepromisering.com/ufc-coming-to-calgary you can see at the end of the post it shows the following line:

Share this:Email Print Facebook StumbleUpon Digg

Now my question is how to show this on the home page after every post.

Please help me in this matter.

Thanks
Somdeb

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing more details. Are you using the sharethis plugin, or manually adding the sharethis code to your template files?

My guess is that you're using the sharethis plugin and that it's hooking into `the_content()` which is NOT the same as `the_excerpt()`. I bet if you change your index.php (or whatever template file is getting used for the header) to use `the_content()` the sharethis buttons will appear. If this is the case you have a couple options: 1. you can leave it that way and manually place the "read more" cut-off on a per-post basis. 2. you can keep using `the_excerpt()` and manually add the sharethis button code after it in your template. It would look something like this...

```
//...
the_excerpt(); ?>
<span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
```

You shouldn't have to worry about the script because it's already included by the plugin, but you will want to add a custom link option so that each button doesn't link to the index page (instead of the homepage). You do that by adding an `st_url` attribute:

```
<span class="st_sharethis" st_url="http://sharethis.com" st_title="Sharing Rocks!"
displayText="ShareThis"></span>
```

(More customization options here: http://help.sharethis.com/customization/custom-buttons)

In your case, you'll almost certainly want to use the permalink as the value:

```
<span class="st_sharethis" st_url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></span>
```

Hope this helps.

PS: Did Nick's knee problem get solved after he left TUF?